# The StreamingContext.textfilestream file is read, but no results are displayed on the console

Tags: apache-spark

```
def textfile={
   val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))

   val lines = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://master:9000/streaming/")
   val words = lines.flatMap(_.split("\\s"));

   val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1));
   val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _);

   wordCounts.print();
   ssc.start();
   ssc.awaitTermination();

}
```

The results do not show up

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textFileStream` only scans the new files after you start the streaming application. If you want to scan the existing files, you can use the following workaround:

```
fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](
  directory,
  filter = path => !path.getName().startsWith("."),
  newFilesOnly = false).map(_._2.toString)
```